# How to grab specific text from a website with Python

Tags: python, web

I was wondering how could I make a program that will grab information from this webiste: https://growtopiagame.com/ (Or any at general), But I don't want to grab every text from it: I just want to grab Part where it says "4231 Players Online",
And store it in variable that I can use later on...

Comment: `Beautifulsoup` should help

Comment: https://elitedatascience.com/python-web-scraping-libraries

Comment: It'll be better if you decide to try on your own first and show us that code.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unfortunately this isn't a discussion forum or tutorial service. Please take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  You should invest some time working your way through [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html), practicing the examples. It will give you an introduction to the tools Python has to offer and you may even start to get ideas for solving your problem.

Comment: dude don't be toxic... Chill bro , we can discuss on IG if you have any problems :) (7% bd fat here)

Comment: @WellDirth, he is not being toxic. StackOverflow is indeed not a discussion forum. Here in StackOverflow, we encourage genuine efforts in actually solving their problems. We do not like spoon feeding people because that deprives you of the opportunity to learn. We want to help people learn and grow. In order to do so, we rather guide people than blatantly throw them the code. We are not doing this out of sheer ignorance. We are doing this to help you become better at what you want to do - programming. So, try it out on your own first then shoot us a question when you need help.

Answer (score 2):

Extracting data from website are generally called web scraping. Glad to have such powerful packages in python to do this task , such as `Selenium`and  `BeautifulSoup`. Please check [this](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-scrape-websites-with-python-and-beautifulsoup-5946935d93fe) for more details how to do web scraping.

Answer (score 2):

Use a web scraping library. For Python, we can use [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

What you'd want to do is first get the whole page and parse the HTML you get. You'd do something like:

```
# I'm skipping the necessary packages you need to import.
webpage = urllib2.urlopen('https://growtopiagame.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage,'html.parser')
```

After that, you will continue using BeautifulSoup. But how do we get the online player count?

Simple! We just need to check the HTML code of the website first. From the website, open<sup>1</sup> "Inspect Element" on the text you want to parse. In your case, you we'd get the following HTML snippet:

```
<!--There are more code lines above. -->
<div class="server-status">
    Server is up |   
    <span class="counter">40961</span> Players online!
</div>
<!--There are more codes below. -->
```

I left out the unnecessary HTML code as far as your problem is concerned.

From the snippet we get, notice that the online player count (40961, as of current writing) is inside the `<span>` element with the `"counter"` class.

From there, we can now extract the online player count by just instructing BeautifulSoup to get the text of `span.counter`. To be more accurate, we can , instead, get the text of `div.server-status span.counter`.

I'll leave writing the rest of the code up to you.

---

Footnote

1. I'm not sure if it is the proper term. Is "open" the proper term?

Comment: Bruh I'd like whole code because I suck at programming ...

Comment: @WellDirth, StackOverflow is not built to provide "easy code". We do provide some code but usually only when it solves the problem **and** we notice that the OP has provided evidence that he has worked on his problem on his own first than just going to SO to ask for some code. Using the "I suck at programming" excuse is not a good one. We want to see genuine effort. So, try it on your own first and ask us for help when you are stuck in a bug or problem.